# Rotate Google map issue in newer Google play Service 6.1 or heigher

Tags: android, google-maps, rotation, compass

currently i am rotating google map (api v2) using compass sensor by passing bearing value to CameraPosition.bearing method to rotate map.

```
 public void updateCamera(float bearing) {
        if(LocationObj!=null) {
            CameraPosition currentPlace = new CameraPosition.Builder(mMap.getCameraPosition())
                    .zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                    .bearing(bearing).build();
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(currentPlace));
        }
    }
```

but suddenly when i upgrade my nexus to lollipop (api 21) google map automatically scroll downwards with rotation continuously .is this bug of google play service?
and i can not pass currnet LatLng and zoom value to CameraPosition.Builder target and zoom method. because i want to rotate map as well as zoom and change the position of map using current camera position using getCameraPosition().

***UPDATE***
today i update my nexus 7 with lollipop which contain lower version of google service api and my map rotate perfectly fine . so according to me this is the bug of google play service